# How to find the column having duplicate value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table:

```
create table #t
(     
    ID int,      
    value nvarchar(5)
)

insert #t 
values (1,'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'A'), (3, 'B')
```

Sample data:

```
ID  value    
------------
1   A    
2   B    
3   A    
3   B
```

For my project I need the ID which has having both the values

Result :

```
ID
3
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part.  What have you tried and found to not work?

Comment: :) .. I am a beginner to Ms-Sql.

Answer (score 0):

To get IDs having 2 values

```
select id 
from #t
group by id
having count(distinct value) >= 2
```

or to get all IDs having A and B

```
select id 
from #t
where value in ('A','B')
group by id
having count(distinct value) = 2
```

or to make it more generic to get IDs having all values

```
select id 
from #t
group by id
having count(distinct value) = (select count(distinct value) from #t)
```

Comment: Thanks Jurgen for the answer